# .htaccess restrict access to multiple url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i'm writing some url rewrite conditions to restrict access to

http://example.com/admin and
http://example.com/index.php/admin

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php/admin
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.111
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.112
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.113
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.114
RewriteRule ^.*$ /deny.html [R=302,L]
```

i only know how to make index.php/admin successfully to be restricted, but not /admin , how can i add one more url into above rules?

Comment: create a .htaccess in the folder admin containing: RewriteRule ^.*$ /deny.html [R=302,L]

Comment: or you could use: Order deny, allow Allow from {ip here to allow} and simply put that in the folder, then everybody who is not from that specific ip will get the acces denied notification to get the custom deny page use: ErrorDocument 403 /deny.html